# Bodhi installation hangs

Tags: system-installation, bodhi

I am currently trying to install Bodhi linux (version as of 2014_07_09) to my Laptop.
I booted from USB-drive into the live environment and hit install. After some attempts I even found on the Distro's website that they do **NOT** recommend using the "download updates during installation"-checkbox, so I didn't do that anymore.

Regardless though:
I get to choose the language and to the quickchecks (Disk-space, AC-plugged, internet) and ,as I chose not to bother connecting to the internet at all, to the "are you sure you don't want to connect to one of these WiFis"-screens.
After that I hit "continue", the cursor turns to the wristwatch and then I wait and nothing happens.
The system is very responsive: I can do other things or easily cancel the installation, just the installation does not do anything at all. I gave it around 30 minutes and nothing.
Furthermore, since the installer looks a lot like Ubuntu's and also because I haven't decided anything in that direction, I expected to first see at least the "choose and edit partitions"-interface.

Any advice on what I might do to fix this or at least find the reasons for the stoppage?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mount the dvd-player (in fancy theme will be easier at 2.4) and at least one partition or flash. When it asks unmount /dev to continue say NO and make the changes afterwards. Of course, there must be an active partition for booting and take care (if you have Windows, not to have more than 4 primary - including system reserved).