# Bodhi Linux - Hanging on Install

Tags: system-installation, bodhi

*[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143979/bodhi-installation-hangs?s=10%7C0.1667) may be related, but it is woefully unresolved, and I don't have the reputation to add to it.*

**Short Version:**

> While running the Bodhi 2.4 live OS from a thumbdrive, opening the Install
>   wizard only allows me to get **two steps** in ("select language", "check
>   requirements") before hanging indefinitely on my 5-year-old rig's freshly-formatted 1TB internal drive.
>
> *Is there something I am missing?*

**Long Version:**

> I recently butchered an Ubuntu 14.10 primary OS by fiddling where I shouldn't, *though it had been
>   going downhill since upgrading from 14.04 anyways*. While
>   deleting the Linux partition I also deleted GRUB and couldn't figure out how to get into
>   my Windows 7 dual-boot. So I decided to just wipe my drive and start
>   fresh, *assuming this would be the cleanest route and also so that I could try something new.*
>
> I formatted my 1TB Samsung internal as ext4 with a 12GB Linux Swap
>   partition. I have Bodhi Linux running from a 2TB USB flash drive. The
>   live OS is working just fine, *it's what I'm using to compose this
>   post*. I can install software, tweak configurations, and check my
>   drive(s) in GParted. The one thing I can't get it to do is install. It hangs on the screen titled "Preparing to install Bodhi" with two green-for-go checks next to the requirements ("has at least 3.1 GB available drive space","is connected to the internet"). I hit **Continue**, and then **Continue** and **Back** become greyed out, and then that's it. I've restarted and done this at least six times. I checked the drive for errors, it passed. I even unplugged my other two internals, *because, I don't know, why not*. I have hit **Continue** after ensuring that "Download updates while installing" is checked and also after ensuring that it is deselected. Today, just in case I was being too impatient, I hit **Continue**, left for my 8-hour work day, and came back to the exact same screen I had left this morning.
>
> This never throws an error message, and nothing ever locks up. In
>   fact, I'm looking at the very Install wizard screen under discussion
>   right now. The system is still perfectly responsive, and the Install
>   wizard is refusing to do anything more than grey out the **Back** and
>   **Continue** buttons. The wizard is still functional in that I can use the **Quit** button without any issues, I can select and deselect the
>   checkbox next to "Download updates while installing", and I can move
>   the application window around.

---

**Source Specs:**

- SanDisk Cruzer Micro 2GB *thumb drive*

**Destination Specs:**

- Gigabyte GA-MA770-UD3 *Mobo*
- AMD Phenom II X4 920 64bit *CPU*
- 6GB DDR3 DIMM 1066MHz (2GBx3) *RAM*
- Sapphire Radeon HD 4830 *GPU*
- Samsung 1TB 7200RPM *HDD*

**lshw output:**

```
    *-disk
         description: ATA Disk
         product: SAMSUNG HD103SJ
         physical id: 0.1.0
         bus info: scsi@5:0.1.0
         logical name: /dev/sda
         version: 1AJ1
         serial: S246J90Z199477
         size: 931GiB (1TB)
         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
         configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=10729873
       *-volume:0
            description: EXT4 volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 1
            capacity: 919GiB
            capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes
            large_files huge_files dir_nlink extents ext4 ext2 initialized
            configuration: created=2015-01-18 19:21:56 filesystem=ext4 
            label=Samsung1000ext4 modified=2015-01-19 22:19:56 state=clean
       *-volume:1
            description: Extended partition
            physical id: 2
            bus info: scsi@5:0.1.0,2
            logical name: /dev/sda2
            size: 12GiB
            capacity: 12GiB
            capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
```

Comment: Have you tried reburning the image? A lot of times something happens during downloading or burning and the installer acts strange. Your hard drive shouldn't have anything to do with it, as long as the OS can read and write to it.

Comment: I will give that a shot as soon as I get home tonight. I was naively assuming that that wasn't the problem since the live OS was working so nicely. Stupid assumption, I know.

Comment: @Ohnana I don't think I can use my "solution" as an answer. I burned a new Bodhi image to another thumb drive, only instead of using the same 2.4 version I opted to go for the 3.0 RC2. It all went smoothly on the first try, and I have a functioning desktop once again. Can this question be resolved without starting over with 2.4?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. Do you mean marking this question as complete?

Comment: @Ohnana Sorry, yes. I feel weird about abandoning the question unanswered. There isn't much in the way of discussing Bodhi installation issues here, so I would like this to be helpful to anyone else with similar predicaments.

Comment: Well, answer your question with "I downloaded it again and used the newest version" and then accept. Self-answers are perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making the assumption, based on Ohnana's suggestion, that the issue was a corrupted Bodhi image on my thumbdrive. I burned a fresh image of Bodhi (3.0 this time instead of 2.4) to another thumbdrive and was able to quickly and effortlessly install the OS without a hitch.

Should anyone else run into a similar problem, I suggest first reburning the ISO and starting over. That seems overtly obvious now, after the fact, but I didn't think to try it then so let this serve as a reminder to all others.

*Get your Bodhi ISO [**here**](http://www.bodhilinux.com/).*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. after taking your advise, I downloaded and created a new boot drive. 
I thought it happened again. while I was searching for other ideas on the other computer, it suddenly moved forward. 
So, maybe the solution is time, even though it doesn't seem 'thinking'..